# minimize frobenius norm subject to rank condition

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I'm trying to solve the following problem:
Let A be (a, b) matrix.  Given l < min ( a, b) , solve:

\begin{align}
\min_{rank(X)= l}    || A - X ||_{Fro}^2
\end{align}
I'm novice in optimization and don't know how to take the rank constraint into account. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a generic optimization problem, it is a very hard problem since rank constraints typically are intractable.

However, this particular problem has an analytic solution in terms of the SVD
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation